# Генерация QR-кодов в C#

Tags: c#

У меня проект на C#. Нужно добавить возможность генерировать из вводимого текста qr-коды. Скачал из инета и попробовал различные библиотеки (BarcodeLib.Barcode.WinForms.dll, KeepAutomation.Barcode.Windows.dll, MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll, OnBarcode.Barcode.WinForms.dll, QRCodeEncodeNET.dll, zxing.dll). Почему-то ни одна из них корректно не работает с русским текстом. Не могу понять, эти библиотеки не предназначены для русского языка, или я что-то не так делаю? Может кто сталкивался, подскажите плиз пути решения.

Comment: В итоге использую следующий код от библиотеки ZXing (за основу взят пример ICE):

Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object> opt = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();
opt.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "windows-1251");
QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bm = qrCodeWriter.encode("мой текст", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300, opt);          
BarcodeWriter barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
barcodeWriter.Write(bm).Save("c:\\1251.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: Это ответ? Если да, то лучше его оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

1) Берем ZXing

2) В код добавляем:

```
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object>();
hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "windows-1251");
MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(new QRCodeWriter().encode("кириллица тут",    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400, hints);
```

Comment: Извини, ошибся в первом посте, zxing до этого не проверял. Добавил ссылку на него в проект.
Мой код не определяет классы Map, HashMap и MatrixToImageWriter. Откуда брать, подскажи плиз.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось так:

```
ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions opt = new ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
{
    CharacterSet = "utf-8",
    Height = 200,
    Width = 200
};
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    Options = opt
};
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не быть проще? [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes)

Comment: у меня не web-приложение, а winform. И на компах пользователей подключения к инету зачастую нет.

Comment: @TabakovAleksey, в данном случае нет никакой разницы, какого типа приложение. А вот насчет подключения к инету - да. Но такие вещи желательно указывать в вопросе :)