# Создание QR-кодов в приложении winforms c# с помощью Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, crystalreport

Для добавления штрих-кодов в отчет я воспользовался шрифтом Free 3 of 9, а как быть с QR-кодами? Есть ли какой-нибудь похожий способ для них?

Если нет, то при создании QR-кода этим способом ([Генерация QR-кодов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/309285/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-qr-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-c) - с помощью библиотеки ZXing), можно ли его будет закинуть в отчет? Подскажет кто-нибудь?

Comment: [Видосик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32u7kb9DYEk) в тему.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097866/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-string-%d0%b2-datetime

Comment: @Bulson спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @Igor да.. забыл. Не помню уже как так вышло :(